# How to sync all photos on Android with Amazon Prime Photos?

Tags: photos, sync

Here's some background information:

- I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 Android phone.
- I have an Amazon Prime account.
- I have some photos stored in folders on my memory card.
- I have some photos stored in my phone's memory.
- I have some photos stored with the Picasa icon.
- I can see all of these photo albums on the phone using the Android "Gallery" app
- I installed the Amazon Cloud Drive App on the phone and set it to Autosave Photos.

The problem is that it only seems to upload the Photos stored in memory on the phone not the other locations i.e. memory card, picasa.

How can I get all of these photos (no matter how they are stored) copies to the Amazon Prime Photos cloud?

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer to my question in case any one else cares from the Amazon support page:

> To upload your photos and videos:
>    From the Android Gallery on your Android device: 
>   Open the photo, album, or video you want to upload.
>   Tap the Share icon, and then select Cloud Drive.

Answer (score 1):

Now you actually can just download the official app from Amazon:

https://www.amazon.com/photos/home

It does all that you need automatically and without any issues.